# Display user data in Next.js 14 standards without extra libs

Tags: react-typescript, next.js14

I'm following the Next.js 14 Learning Tutorial (https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/fetching-data) and I'm able to do everything they show.

To show data in the frontend they first create a file with the definitions of our data:

**definitions.tsx**

```
// This file contains type definitions for your data.
// It describes the shape of the data, and what data type each property should accept.
// For simplicity of teaching, we're manually defining these types.
// However, these types are generated automatically if you're using an ORM such as Prisma.
export type User = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
};
```

then in another file, we have the query:
**data.tsx**

```
import { sql } from '@vercel/postgres';
import { unstable_noStore as noStore } from 'next/cache';
import { User } from './definitions';

export async function fetchUsers() {
  noStore();

  try {
    const data = await sql<User>`SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 5`;
    const result = data.rows;
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Database Error:', error);
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data.');
  }
}
```

the ui with the fetched data is created in another file.
I will write the example they give first:
**latest-invoices.tsx**

```
import { ArrowPathIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { lusitana } from '@/app/ui/fonts';
import { LatestInvoice } from '@/app/lib/definitions';

export default async function LatestInvoices({
  latestInvoices,
}: {
  latestInvoices: LatestInvoice[];
}) {
  return (
    <div className="flex w-full flex-col md:col-span-4 lg:col-span-4">
      <h2 className={`${lusitana.className} mb-4 text-xl md:text-2xl`}>
        Latest Invoices
      </h2>
      <div className="flex grow flex-col justify-between rounded-xl bg-gray-50 p-4">
        {<div className="bg-white px-6">
          {latestInvoices.map((invoice, i) => {
            return (
              <div
                key={invoice.id}
                className={clsx(
                  'flex flex-row items-center justify-between py-4',
                  {
                    'border-t': i !== 0,
                  },
                )}
              >
...
```

it's way more complex than what I want to do. I want to display the user data in rows in the page. For that I created a simple file like that:

**user-list.tsx**

```
import { User } from '@/app/lib/definitions';

export default async function UserList({
    userList,
}: {
  userList: User[];
}) {
    userList.map((variable, i) => {
      return (
        <p>
            {variable.id} <br />
            {variable.name} <br />
            {variable.email} <br />
            {variable.password}
        </p>
  )});
}
```

Using that I receive the following error message:

```
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

   6 | userList: User[];
   7 | }) {
>  8 |   userList.map((variable, i) => {
     |           ^
   9 |     return (
  10 |       <p>
  11 |           {variable.id} <br />
```

As a matter of fact, I'm not very aware what this chunck of the code (latest-invoices.tsx) makes and it will be great if someone could explain it to me. Is it specific of TypeScript?

```
export default async function LatestInvoices({
  latestInvoices,
}: {
  latestInvoices: LatestInvoice[];
}) {
```

and in my file (user-list.tsx), I tried to copy this logic above without knowing well what I was doing and for sure the problem is here. It's mapping somehow the array from the users query, but I'm not sure if the data is fit to an array...

```
export default async function UserList({
    userList,
}: {
  userList: User[];
}) {
    userList.map((variable, i) => {
```

So I'd appreciate if you could show me the simpliest way to display the user data like this:

id01 - UserName01 - email01 - password01
id02 - UserNmae02 - email02 - password02
etc.

**== EDIT ==**
The fetching functions and the components are called / used in a fourth file called
**page.tsx**

```
import LatestInvoices from '@/app/ui/dashboard/latest-invoices';
import UserList from '@/app/ui/dashboard/user-list';

import {
  fetchLatestInvoices,
  fetchUser
} from '@/app/lib/data';

export default async function Page() {

  const latestInvoices = await fetchLatestInvoices();
  const userList = await fetchUsers();

  return (
    <main>
      <h1 className={`${lusitana.className} mb-4 text-xl md:text-2xl`}>
        Dashboard
      </h1>

      <div className="mt-6 grid grid-cols-1 gap-6 md:grid-cols-4 lg:grid-cols-8">
        {<LatestInvoices latestInvoices={latestInvoices} />}
      </div>

      <div className="mt-6 grid grid-cols-1 gap-6 md:grid-cols-4 lg:grid-cols-8">
        {<UserList userList={userList} />}
      </div>

    </main>
  );
}
```

This is giving me the following error message:

```
'UserList' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its type '({ userList, }: { userList: User[]; }) => Promise<void>' is not a valid JSX element type.
    Type '({ userList, }: { userList: User[]; }) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(props: any, deprecatedLegacyContext?: any) => ReactNode'.
      Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
        Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLikeOfReactNode'.
          Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
            Type '<TResult1 = void, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: void) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) | null | undefined) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = ReactNode, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: ReactNode) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) | null | undefined) => PromiseLike<...>'.
              Types of parameters 'onfulfilled' and 'onfulfilled' are incompatible.
                Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
                  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.ts(2786)
(alias) function UserList({ userList, }: {
    userList: User[];
}): Promise<void>
import UserList
```

Comment: Where are you calling the fetching function and where are using the UserList Components ?

Comment: Oh yes, I will edit the question to insert this info as well. In another file called page.tsx that in the tutorial calls all fetching functions and display the components.

Comment: Now I see there are lots of Error beacuse of syntax and missing code

Comment: @ALFaizAhmed where are the errors? All files (definitions.tsx, data.tsx, latest-invoice.tsx, page.tsx) are direct from the Next.js tutorial. Only user-list.tsx is my own file, the only one that is wrong somewhere. And of course this  chunck where I call the component <UserList /> in page.tsx.

Comment: lets start with fetch user function you are not returning anything in catch function, in try{} there is not typscript awaited type assign, In User list component you are directly map user, first use react.fragment and then wrap user.map array inside.